# Multiple modeling in Searckick using elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch

I am using searckick gem which is based on elasticsearch. I tried doing searching for one mmodel its working fine. But now I want to search across two models. I tried many thing like:
`Searchkick.search("thequery", [Model1, Model2, Model3], other_options)`
and this
`Model1.search("thequery", index_name: [Model1.index.name, Model2.index.name, Model3.index.name])` In first solution I am getting error in search keyword. Thanks in advance.

Error : `NoMethodError: undefined method 'search' for Searchkick:Module`

Comment: Might be will help you this https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/53 and https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#advanced

Comment: I tried both the things but its not working.

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: Have a look @RajarshiDas i edited the question with error.

Comment: is your model name is `Searchkick` ? Look it is pretty clear that search is working for `Model1.search` ? but you can not use the module `Searchkick` as a mode class

Comment: No i think thats the key word `Searchkick`. We are specifying the model inside the brackets `Searchkick.search("images", [Myfolder, Myfile], where: {user_id: 1})`

Answer (score 0):

The gem is probably out of date.

Try to run `bundle update --source searchkick`. It will only update Searchkick.